# compiling aqemu under opensuse with gcc/cmake/make problems

Tags: gcc, makefile, qemu, opensuse

Hi coders all over there,

i am using openSUSE linux and installed gcc as compiler.
I am trying to compile AQEMU -> https://sourceforge.net/projects/aqemu/?source=typ_redirect

All required Dependencies are installed:

ofc i already tried to solve the problem by my own(google,stackoverflow...) but i dont find any solution.
Here is my log, may any tipps how to continue?
http://pastebin.com/rbeBSSMZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Where/How do you see that it is a source code problem?(because it seems like i am the only one with this problem, so i guess locally smth is broken). I checked that linked question, and can not really find smth that is related to my problem, but may i do not see it. I tried to clean the build ( rm -tf build) and rebuilded but the error is still the same.